# Listen Eviction Event

Tags: ignite

I am using off-heap and persistent is disabled. My data region max size is 20MB. I am using RANDOM_2_LRU as page eviction mode. when eviction happens I want to listen to the EVT_CACHE_ENTRY_EVICTED. I have written the following code but its not working.I saw in ignite logs it say page-based eviction started.

```
     CacheEntryEvictionListener listener = new CacheEntryEvictionListener(logger);
     ignite.events(ignite.cluster().forCacheNodes(cacheName)).localListen(listener,EventType.EVT_CACHE_ENTRY_EVICTED);  
        
     IgniteBiPredicate<UUID, CacheEvent> biPredicate = IgniteUtil.getCacheEventBiPredicate(cacheName);
     IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> predicate = IgniteUtil.getCacheEventPredicate(cacheName);

     // Process remote events
     ignite.events(ignite.forCacheNodes(cacheName)).remoteListen(biPredicate, predicate, EventType.EVT_CACHE_ENTRY_EVICTED);
```

Comment: Did you enable events recording? With config.setIncludeEventTypes(EVT_CACHE_ENTRY_EVICTED)

Comment: Yes.igniteConfig.setIncludeEventTypes(org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT,
    org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED,
    org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_EXPIRED,
    org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_NODE_LEFT,
    org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_NODE_FAILED,
    org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_NODE_JOINED,
    org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_ENTRY_EVICTED);

Answer (score 0):

`EVT_CACHE_ENTRY_EVICTED` is triggered when there's an *on*-heap eviction. This might happen if you have a near-cache or an on-heap cache.

Unfortunately, there is no event for off-heap eviction. (A possible reason for this is that eviction is performed at a *page* rather than a *record* level.)

Comment: is there any way to listen to page based eviction?

Comment: I don't think so. What's the use case?

Comment: We have two caches c1 and c2. c1 has the main record and c2 has some mapping. Once the record from c1 id is deleted because of eviction we want to listen to the eviction event and remove the mapping from c2.